# Iterating over fields of the same type

Tags: c++, templates

Let say you have the following classes:

```
class Data
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};

class DataOther
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};

class Line
{
public:
    Data Right;
    Data Left;
};

class LineOther
{
public:
    DataOther Right;
    DataOther Left;
}
```

I have quite a few classes that are structured this way, and when I want to run code over both "sides" of the data I typically do something like this:

```
enum class Side { RIGHT, LEFT };
template<typename T>
auto GetBySide(const Side &side, T &data) -> decltype(data.Right) & 
{ 
    return side == Side::Left ? data.Left : data.Right; 
}
```

And then in the code:

```
Line l;
LineOther lOther;
for(auto &side: {Sides::LEFT, Sides::Right})
{
      auto &d = GetBySide(side, l);
      auto &dOther = GetBySide(side, lOther);

      // Do some stuff with the data
}
```

Now the down side of this, is that it's run-time so not much optimization can be done, though I suppose a compiler might unroll the loop.

Any other ideas on how to structure the code?

Comment: Consider using `std::pair` instead. It even has `get()` methods for accessing elements by index or type at compile-time

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about unrolling, you may replace:

```
Line l;
LineOther lOther;
for (auto &side: {Sides::LEFT, Sides::Right})
{
      auto &d = GetBySide(side, l);
      auto &dOther = GetBySide(side, lOther);

      // Do some stuff with the data
}
```

by something like:

```
template <Side side>
void foo(Line& l, LineOther& lOther) {
      auto &d = GetBySide(side, l);
      auto &dOther = GetBySide(side, lOther);

      // Do some stuff with the data
}
```

and

```
Line l;
LineOther lOther;
foo<Sides::LEFT>(l, lOther);
foo<Sides::Right>(l, lOther);
```

Answer (score 0):

"I have quite a few classes that are structured this way" it seems that you can leave only one of them. Or at least utilize inheritance or other technique to avoid duplication:

```
// Declare base class instead of copypasting fields.
class BaseLine
{
public:
    int Right{};
    int Left{};
};

class Line: public BaseLine
{};

class LineOther: public BaseLine
{};

int main()
{
    Line l;
    l.Right = 45; l.Left = 89;
    LineOther lOther;
    lOther.Right = 74; lOther.Left = 33;
    // Use pointer to member to iterate over fields.
    for(auto p_side: {&BaseLine::Right, &BaseLine::Left})
    {
       ::std::cout << (l.*p_side) << ::std::endl;
       ::std::cout << (lOther.*p_side) << ::std::endl;
    }   
}
```

[Online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VCmhmLoGOJVWRivm)